# MIPS string first character not showing

Tags: string, mips

So a weird problem is happening with my MARS MIPS simulator.

My string that takes the user's name is seemingly deleting the first character of their name. I can't figure out for the life of me why.

```
.data
    height: .asciiz "enter your height"
    weight: .asciiz "enter your weight"
    little: .float 18.5
    medium: .float 25
    large: .float 30
    fpconstant: .float 703
    bmi: .float
    under: .asciiz "This is considered underweight"
    health: .asciiz "This is considered healthy"
    overweight: .asciiz "This is considered overweight"
    obese: .asciiz "This is considered obese."
    name: .asciiz ", here are your BMI results\n"
    prompt: .asciiz "Please enter your name"
    buffer: .space 20

.text

main: li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 8
syscall

la $a0, buffer  # load byte space into address
    li $a1, 20      # allot the byte space for string
   move $t6, $a0   # save string to t6
   syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, weight
syscall

li $v0, 6
syscall



movf.s $f1, $f0 #f1 now contains weight, will continue after this correction has been made.
l.s $f2, fpconstant
mul.s $f0, $f1, $f2

movf.s $f1, $f0
movf.s $f12, $f0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, height
syscall

li $v0, 6
syscall


movf.s $f2, $f0 #f2 now contains height, will continue after this correction has been made.
mul.s $f0, $f2, $f2
movf.s $f2, $f0
movf.s $f12, $f0

div.s $f3, $f1, $f2 #f3 is our BMI
movf.s $f12, $f3

la $a0, buffer  # reload byte space to primary address
    move $a0, $t6  # primary address = t6 address (load pointer)
    li $v0, 4       # print string


syscall #Problem


la $a0, name
move $t0, $a0
syscall


li $v0, 2
syscall

l.s $f4, little
c.lt.s $f3,$f4
bc1t underweight  #Branch if specified FP condition flag true (BC1T, not BCLT) : If Coprocessor 1 condition flag specified by immediate is true (one) then branch to statement at label's address       #  Compare less than single precision : If $f0 is less than $f1, set Coprocessor 1 condition flag 0 true else set it false

l.s $f4, medium
c.lt.s $f3,$f4
bc1t mid  

l.s $f4, large
c.lt.s $f3,$f4
bc1t big  

li $v0, 4
la $a0, obese
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

underweight: 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, under
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

mid: 
li $v0, 4
la $a0, health
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

big: 

li $v0, 4
la $a0, overweight
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

I apologize for bad formatting-- this is my first question I've ever asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem was much farther up in the code (e.g. when you first read in the name with `syscall 8`). The `la $a0,buffer` was coming *after* the `syscall` (i.e. the bug)

Also, it seems you're a bit liberal with some `syscall`. (e.g. `underweight:` has *two* `syscall 10` but only one is required).
I've annotated your code and cleaned up some comments, and fixed the bug. I also reformatted it:

```
    .data
height:     .asciiz     "enter your height: "
weight:     .asciiz     "enter your weight: "
little:     .float      18.5
medium:     .float      25
large:      .float      30
fpconstant: .float      703
bmi:        .float
under:      .asciiz     " This is considered underweight"
health:     .asciiz     " This is considered healthy"
overweight: .asciiz     " This is considered overweight"
obese:      .asciiz     " This is considered obese."
name:       .asciiz     ", here are your BMI results\n"
prompt:     .asciiz     "Please enter your name: "
buffer:     .space      20

    .text

main:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,prompt
    syscall

    j       fix                     # skip over [broken] original code

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # NOTE/BUG: here is the original code
    li      $v0,8
    syscall

    la      $a0,buffer              # load byte space into address

    li      $a1,20                  # allot the byte space for string
    move    $t6,$a0                 # save string to t6
    syscall

    li      $v0,8
    syscall
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # NOTE/FIX: here is the fixed code
fix:
    la      $a0,buffer              # get address of name buffer
    li      $a1,20                  # allot the byte space for string
    li      $v0,8
    syscall
    move    $t6,$a0                 # save string to t6

    # strip newline for pretty print
strip:
    lbu     $t0,0($a0)              # get char
    addiu   $a0,$a0,1               # advance to next char
    beqz    $t0,strip_done          # EOS? if yes, done
    bne     $t0,0x0A,strip          # newline? if no, loop
    sb      $zero,-1($a0)           # strip newline
strip_done:

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,weight
    syscall

    li      $v0,6
    syscall

    # f1 now contains weight, will continue after this correction has been made.
    movf.s  $f1,$f0
    l.s     $f2,fpconstant
    mul.s   $f0,$f1,$f2

    movf.s  $f1,$f0
    movf.s  $f12,$f0

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,height
    syscall

    li      $v0,6
    syscall

    # f2 now contains height, will continue after this correction has been made.
    movf.s  $f2,$f0
    mul.s   $f0,$f2,$f2
    movf.s  $f2,$f0
    movf.s  $f12,$f0

    div.s   $f3,$f1,$f2             # f3 is our BMI
    movf.s  $f12,$f3

    la      $a0,buffer              # reload byte space to primary address
    move    $a0,$t6                 # primary address = t6 (load pointer)
    li      $v0,4                   # print string

    # NOTE: this is _not_ the true source of the problem -- see above
    syscall                         # Problem

    la      $a0,name
    move    $t0,$a0
    syscall

    li      $v0,2
    syscall

    l.s     $f4,little
    c.lt.s  $f3,$f4

    # Branch if specified FP condition flag true (BC1T, not BCLT) :
    # If Coprocessor 1 condition flag specified by immediate is true (one) then
    # branch to statement at label's address
    # Compare less than single precision :
    # If $f0 is less than $f1, set Coprocessor 1 condition flag 0 true
    # else set it false
    bc1t    underweight

    l.s     $f4,medium
    c.lt.s  $f3,$f4
    bc1t    mid

    l.s     $f4,large
    c.lt.s  $f3,$f4
    bc1t    big

    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,obese
    j       result

underweight:
    la      $a0,under
    j       result

mid:
    la      $a0,health
    j       result

big:
    la      $a0,overweight
    j       result

result:
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The second syscall in underweight was an oversight on my part-- I didn't even notice it.